# port 443: Connection refused in R on personal computer

Tags: r, curl, http-status-codes, connection-refused

I am following an API tutorial:

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/r-api-tutorial/

and step 1 - I attempted a GET request

```
res = GET("https://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")
```

I immediately hit a roadblock

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
> Failed to connect to api.open-notify.org port 443: Connection refused

I tried HTTP instead of HTTPS

and I tried removing a '/'

All of these attempts and the original attempt all resulted in a connection timeout.

I am working on my own personal laptop PC. From what I have read online, some responses have made a point about corporate or work computers, and also firewalls. I have no idea whether or not this is relevant.

The expected result should be a Status: 200

> Response [https://api.open-notify.org/astros.json]
> Date: 2020-01-30 18:07
> Status: 200
> Content-Type: application/json
> Size: 314 B

How do I resolve a 443: Connection refused result?

Comment: Did you try it in your web browser? I did, and it returns "unable to connect". Perhaps the website is down. With the unambiguity of `https://api.open-notify.org/astros.json` connecting over port 443 to a clear name, there is nothing more you can do in R or any language to accommodate the fact that the remote server is not responding.

Comment: But I did get a 200 (successful) connection with `res <- httr::GET("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")` (http). I went to open-notify.org which hinted I could visit http://open-notify.org/Open-Notify-API/People-In-Space/, which had a link to http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json ... which works. Having said that, it looks as if their SSL cert is non-existent, wrong-domain, expired, or something else ... it would not work for me.

Comment: Awesome,  res <- httr::GET("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")  worked!